# Gradle Composite Build: How to Disable an Included Build Task from the Root Project?

Tags: gradle

I have a composite Gradle (7.x) build and want to edit the root project gradle file to permanently prevent a specific included task from executing.  I can successfully accomplish this from the command line with `-x :included-build:bad-task` but cannot figure out how to permanently accomplish the same thing within the root gradle script.  None of the solutions from these questions seem to work:

- [How can I disable a task in build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47192746/how-can-i-disable-a-task-in-build-gradle)
- [Gradle disable automatic subproject execution for specific task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903863/gradle-disable-automatic-subproject-execution-for-specific-task)

Answer (score 0):

If you know "how" it's included, you can remove it.

For example, `check` depends on `checkstyleTest`, and can be removed via `check.dependsOn.remove("checkstyleTest")`

See here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-remove-a-task-dependency/7481

It might be a matter of some detective work to find where it's brought in.  Things like `./gradlew whateverTask --dry-run` can be used to show the progression.  Various temporary tasks could be used to output config information.

### Edit 1

Understanding it is hard to know exactly your needs without more context.  But, depending on your needs, the below might work from your top project:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    childProjects["included-build"].tasks.build.dependsOn -= "bad-task"
}
```

The main points being...

- The task is removed after the project is evaluated (so it exists first).
- The remove uses the `-=` operator.  Prevents `Removing a task dependency from a task instance is not supported.` which happens if you use `.remove`
- Using Gradle 8.0.1

Running this with something like successfully removes `check` from `build`.

> `childProjects["application"].tasks.build.dependsOn -= "check"`

Comment: Sorry I'm not following here.  I know precisely where in my root build the included build is referenced ... now what?  The above link, at a quick glance, doesn't seem applicable to a composite build.

Comment: Edited for sub-project using `gradle.projectsEvaluated`.

Comment: This would probably work for a task brought in via a subproject, but it doesn't find tasks from included builds of a composite build.  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html